# making link between a person name and pronoun in GATE

Tags: nlp, gate

Is it possible to make a link between a person name and its PRP? in GATE E.g i  have  document "Maria Sharapova is  a   tennis player from russia. She participates in international tennis tournament. She is  known for winning Wimbledon, US Open and Australian Open titles as for her looks, decibel-breaking grunts and commercial savvy - all of which made her the world's highest-paid female athlete." i want to annotate the "she" as "Maria Sharapova". I have written the following JAPE rule which identifies a pattern having a PRP after a person name

```
    Phase: Simple
    Input: Lookup Token Split
    Options: control = appelt

   Rule:joblookup
   (
   ({Lookup.majorType == person_first}|
   {Lookup.majorType == person_full})
  ({Token.kind==word})+
  {Split.kind==internal}
  {Token.category==PRP}


):sameathlete
-->
:sameathlete.sameAthlete1 = {kind="athlete", rule="same-athlete"}
```

How can i make the annotation that from She means we are talking about the same person whose name is mentioned 1 or 2 sentence before??
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Co-reference PR for gate?